# Formula to Refresh Report without User Intervention

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've created a report using a OBDC but I'm trying to auto refresh the data every 2 minutes without having to press F5 or click through the toolbar to refresh it manually. Im using version 8.5. Is this a possible feature that can be added into the report?
`autoRefresh = x` This doesn't seem like a function when added to the formula field.

Comment: I don't think this is possible using Crystal Reports alone, but if the report is part of a Java or .NET project, you should be able to use a 3rd party crystal report viewer that supports a refresh command.  Ken Hamady maintains a website with links to many third party crystal report tools.  Here is a [link](https://www.kenhamady.com/productlinks/) to the site.